# OpenLayers autocompletion with Tern

Tags: vim, plugin

I use Tern with Vim and a plugin called YouCompleteMe. I develop principally with two JavaScript libraries: jQuery and OpenLayers. The first one is already supported by Tern. OpenLayers is not.

In order to activate the OpenLayers autocompletion, I configured my .tern-project file as explained [here](http://www.theendian.com/blog/javascript-autocomplete-in-vim-for-jquery/). I wrote the following in it:

```
{
  "libs": [
    "browser",
    "jquery"
  ],
  "loadEagerly": [
    "ol.js"
  ]
}
```

The `ol.js` file is the library. The results is that the OpenLayers autocompletion is not activated. I'm not sure I understand everything with Tern. Do I need to create a JSON type definitions file as described [here](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#typedef)?

Comment: Have you tried with an absolute path for loadEagerly? You shouldn't need to create a type def file, the tern parser should handle reading all the JS files in the load eagerly section

Comment: Yes I tried to load this file: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/ol.js. No success. It's the lib's main file. Do you think it's the one that must be loaded in loadEagerly?